# Resizing iframe causes inconsistent border color

Tags: iframe

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" height="650" width="350"></iframe>
```

[image]

How to get rid of the inconsistent border colors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing iframe causes inconsistent border color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819638/resizing-iframe-causes-inconsistent-border-color)

Answer (score 0):

Just try a little CSS:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" height="650" width="350" style="border: 1px solid #000"></iframe>
```

That should insert a solid black border around your iFrame. With the same color all around it :)