# Resizing iframe causes inconsistent border color

Tags: iframe

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" height="650" width="350"></iframe>
```

[image]

How to get rid of the inconsistent border colors?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have two different border colors: The border colors of the frame itself and the border colors of the scrollbars. You can disable the border altogether by adding the `frameborder=0` attribute. Admittedly, that's like curing a headache with a gun, but it works.